# More than one dropdown for same functionality on same page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My question is how can I display more than one drop downs on same page for same functionality in C#. Let's say I have 3 panels on a page, I want to show a drop down in all three panels but changing the value of one drop down will cause changing the values of others too. 
I can't use id access in JS because if there are 3 drop downs on same page of same ID i.e ID is not unique then Java Script can't perform actions.

Comment: Use class names with different numbers like `drop1`,`drop2` etc. This way you can get different change for different dropdowns in jquery.

Comment: you can do this by clonning the dropdown using jQuery. set the ID as per your choice after clone]

Comment: Sorangwala one thing i needed same change on all drop downs by changing on one, second I don't have specific number of drop downs, panels are dynamic ,I may use arrays like indexing but it will be much more complicated. having same class on all works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply same class to all dropdowns and on change of any of dropdown set that value to all dropdowns please find snippet below.

```js
$(".selectclass").on("change",function(){
   $(".selectclass").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectclass">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="selectclass">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="selectclass">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @SaqibJaved you are always welcome glad to help you  cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different Class all three dropdown and call change event

```
  <select id="ddlUnquie" class="one" >
<option value="firstvalue">first dropdown text</option>
<option value="firstsecond">first second text</option>
</select>
 <br>
<br>
  <select id="ddlUnquie" class="two" >
  <option value="firstvalue">first dropdown text</option>
<option value="firstsecond">first second text</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
 <select id="ddlUnquie" class="three" >
<option value="firstvalue">first dropdown text</option>
<option value="firstsecond">first second text</option>
</select>
```

Below is Jquery code

```
$(".one").change(function()
  {
    alert($(this).val());
  })
   $(".two").change(function()
    {
    alert($(this).val());
   })
  $(".three").change(function()
     {
       alert($(this).val());
    })
```

Also you can use jsfillde link https://jsfiddle.net/1xzkmbtk/

Comment: what if you have 100 panels or 1000 panels? you can't apply different classes and call each of them like this. Having same class name and access it by class works.

Comment: You can you same class name.@SaqibJaved