# How to use Same function for diffrent dropdown with same functionality in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function get(id) {
  $('.get_item').dblclick(function() {
   window.open( base_url + "edit/"+id);
  });
  
  $('.get_customer').dblclick(function() {
     window.open( base_url + "edit/"+id);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="get_item" onchange="get(this.value)" id='cus_id_1'>
  <option value='656'>test1</option>
  <option value='646'>test2</option>
  <option value='687'>test3</option>
</select>
<select class="get_customer" onchange="get(this.value)" id=' cus_id_2 '>
  <option value='566'>test4</option>
  <option value='474'>test5</option>
  <option value='589'>test6</option>
</select>
```

When  select value from dropdown its works after selecting another value its getting previous  selected value Any solution ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More than one dropdown for same functionality on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824952/more-than-one-dropdown-for-same-functionality-on-same-page)

Comment: No [More than one dropdown for same functionality on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824952/more-than-one-dropdown-for-same-functionality-on-same-page) Here the selected value reflecting another dropdown i dont want that

Comment: Your question is not very clear as to what you want to achieve.
Kindly explain what exactly you want to happen when user selects a choice on get_item and when user selects a choice on get_customer?

Comment: i want to get value to  do another tap for edit operation on doubleClick , i will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .dblclick() function will get fired automatically as soon as the field is double clicked as its an handler. You neither need get(id) nor need "onchange" event specified in HTML.

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

If you are looking for onchange handler, you can use Tomalak's solution.

Comment: Here i want to done with double click

Answer (score 0):

```js
function get(ele) {
  alert(ele.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="get_item" onchange="get(this)" id='cus_id_1'>
  <option value='656'>test1</option>
  <option value='646'>test2</option>
  <option value='687'>test3</option>
</select>
<select class="get_customer" onchange="get(this)" id=' cus_id_2 '>
  <option value='566'>test4</option>
  <option value='474'>test5</option>
  <option value='589'>test6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here i want to use double click

Answer (score 0):

- Pass another argument `el` to refer to `this` in the function `get(el , id)`.. And use it `onchange="get(this , this.value)"` Or you can use @jilykate answer by passing only `el` .. `get(el)` and Inside the function use `$(el).val()` or `el.value` instead of `id`
- Use `.off("dblclick")` to stop the previous `dblclick` action
- Enough to use one `dblclick` event handler inside the function

**Example #1** using `get(el , id)`

```js
function get(el , id) {
  $(el).off("dblclick").dblclick(function() {
   console.log("edit/"+id);
   //window.open( base_url + "edit/"+id);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="get_item" onchange="get(this , this.value)" id='cus_id_1'>
  <option value='656'>test1</option>
  <option value='646'>test2</option>
  <option value='687'>test3</option>
</select>
<select class="get_customer" onchange="get(this,this.value)" id=' cus_id_2 '>
  <option value='566'>test4</option>
  <option value='474'>test5</option>
  <option value='589'>test6</option>
</select>
```

**Example #2** using `get(el)`

```js
function get(el) {
  $(el).off("dblclick").dblclick(function() {
   console.log("edit/"+el.value);
   //window.open( base_url + "edit/"+el.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="get_item" onchange="get(this , this.value)" id='cus_id_1'>
  <option value='656'>test1</option>
  <option value='646'>test2</option>
  <option value='687'>test3</option>
</select>
<select class="get_customer" onchange="get(this,this.value)" id=' cus_id_2 '>
  <option value='566'>test4</option>
  <option value='474'>test5</option>
  <option value='589'>test6</option>
</select>
```

**Example #3** using `.on("change"` event with no need for inline events at all

```js
$(".get_item , .get_customer").on("change" , function() {
  $(this).off("dblclick").dblclick(function() {
   console.log("edit/"+this.value);
   //window.open( base_url + "edit/"+this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="get_item" id='cus_id_1'>
  <option value='656'>test1</option>
  <option value='646'>test2</option>
  <option value='687'>test3</option>
</select>
<select class="get_customer" id=' cus_id_2 '>
  <option value='566'>test4</option>
  <option value='474'>test5</option>
  <option value='589'>test6</option>
</select>
```